# WPF Navigation Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

In my project I have two pages, page1 and page2. The navigation between pages is managed by a Frame.

I have notices that when I pass from page1 to page2 and then I come back to page1 my program call page1() constructor each time and this is a problem because page1 have a view model with several bindings and in page1 is also displaied a TreeView with a lot of elements and this cause a slowly change between pages.

I have tried with KeepAlive = "True" but in my case the problem is the same and page1() constructor is called each time.

```
private void Navigate(ViewerMode viewerMode)
    {
        if (_lastViewerMode == viewerMode) return;

        var window = (Application.Current.MainWindow);
        var frame = ((MainWindow)window).Frame;

        var rawPageUri = _uriPath[viewerMode];

        var pageUri = new Uri(rawPageUri, UriKind.Relative);

        frame.Navigate(pageUri);

        _lastViewerMode = viewerMode;
    }

    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<ViewerMode, string> _uriPath = new Dictionary<ViewerMode, string>
    {
        {ViewerMode.OnlinePage,          "Views/Activities.xaml"},
        {ViewerMode.OfflinePage,         "Views/OfflineActivities.xaml"}
    };
```

this is my navigation method, with this I navigate from Activities.xaml to OffliceActivities.xaml pages based of ViewerMode param. In this case I have used URI and not objects.

Could be better in my case to use objects and not URI?
My idea is to store my TreeView content in memory and not reload it each time, **reload it is a problem**.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you create your view models? You shouldn't instantiate them in the constructor of the view. Rather bind to a source outside the `Frame` e.g. a `MainViewModel` which exposes the page models or add them to a `ResourceDictionary`. The key is to reuse the page model instances.

Comment: MyView Models are not declared in my View constructor, but they are declared in my ViewModelLocator. In fact I have noticed that the View constructor is called each time but my My idea is to store my TreeView content in memory and not reload it each time but the View Model constructor is called only the first time.

Comment: I see. So, if you want to prevent the `Frame` from creating new instances of your pages when navigating between them, you must navigate using the content instead of the URI. Or set `Page.KeepAlive` to `true` on each page in XAML code. Or try to use [`NavigationService.AddBackEntry(CustomContentState)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.addbackentry?view=netframework-4.8) to save the content state.